# Table drop-down {display : table-row;} not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm learning HTML5, CSS3. I made a self exercise: instead of using div ul drop menu, trying with table

Why hover it's not working?

http://jsfiddle.net/goldman7911/KQP8Y/

```
tr:hover {
    display : table-row;
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Well you can't hover over something that's not visible.  You can use `table:hover tr` to display the table rows when you hover over the table itself, but that's probably more general than what you want

Comment: I got your point. Many thanks. So I do need make 3 tables, each for each menu drop-down. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/goldman7911/KQP8Y/1/ there is. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tr {
    display: none;
}
tr: hover {
    display: table-row;
}
```

This doesn't make sense since you can't hover over an element that is not being displayed.  Instead, you can do `table:hover tr` as the selector, but this may require a different layout to meet your needs.